# Use pandas.read_csv to convert comma seperate string list into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How can I use Pandas read_csv to convert a big list quickly into a dataframe?

```
import Pandas as pd

x = '1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9'
df = pd.read_csv(x)
```

I know that I could split the string by comma -> put into a list -> convert to dataframe, but was wondering was there a way to do this with pd.read_csv that would be faster?

Comment: Why do you want to use `read_csv`? You can just load it into a data frame.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(x.split(','))`

Answer (score 4):

```
x = '1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.io.common.StringIO(x), header=None)

df

   0  1  2  3  4  5  7  8
0  1  2  3  4  5  7  8  9
```

Is the best you can do with `pd.read_csv`

---

Consider the much larger string

```
y = '\n'.join([','.join(['0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9'] * 100)] * 1000)
```

And compare timing of these two options

```
%timeit pd.DataFrame([l.split(',') for l in y.split('\n')]).astype(int)
%timeit pd.read_csv(pd.io.common.StringIO(y), header=None)

1 loop, best of 3: 200 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 125 ms per loop
```

If all we needed to do is split the string, `split` would be faster.  However, one of the things `pd.read_csv` does for us is parse integers.  That extra overhead gets expensive when having to do it after the split.

Comment: Thanks piRSquared. This works quite slowly for large lists. I with pd.DataFrame([int(s) for s in x[1].split(',')]) I can do it in 0.34 secs or so..I was hoping this route would be faster.

Comment: @kPow989 um, `x[1].split(',')` will only use `split` the **second character of your string `x`**

Comment: sorry meant pd.DataFrame([int(s) for s in x.split(',')])